When add shared preference in pubspec.yml while android studio throw error?
I have used Android Studio 2024 and Flutter 3.24.3.
I am trying to install shared preferences: in Android Studio. it's a throwing error.
I don't know how to solve it.
After the comment shared preference in pubspec.yml, the project run successfully.

I have used Android Studio 2024 and Flutter 3.24.3.
I am trying to install shared preferences: in Android Studio. it's a throwing error.
I don't know how to solve it.
After the comment shared preference in pubspec.yml, the project run successfully.

Please don't screenshots of errors, code or other textual content, but rather post them as actual text and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark them up. Having the content as text makes it accessible, searchable and makes it easier for folks to help you. Also see: Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?

Here are a few common solutions for shared_preferences installation issues:

Add the dependency:
Ensure that you've added the correct version of shared_preferences in your pubspec.yaml file:
dependencies:
  shared_preferences: ^2.1.0  # or the latest version


Flutter Clean:
Run flutter clean and then flutter pub get to remove old builds and refresh dependencies.

Check Compatibility:
Make sure that the shared_preferences package version you're using is compatible with Flutter 3.24.3.

Update Gradle and SDK:
Ensure that your Gradle and Android SDK versions are up-to-date, as outdated versions might cause issues with dependencies like shared_preferences.



Hi there, I have followed this step but it still is not working, and I have the same issue while the SQLite installation

Due to an Android Studio SDK update, this issue is appearing. Downgrade the Android SDK version, it may resolve the problem.

What version of Android Studio SDK is required to downgrade to? That would make this answer a bit more future-proof.

I’m having exactly the same issue. Were you able to resolve
